# Simple for loop in R producing "replacement has length zero" in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I am a novice in R, and so what seemed to work fine in C and Python, surprisingly breaks down in R.
I am trying to calculate the product of the first 1000 Fibonacci numbers. Here is the full code:

```
#PRRODUCT OF FIBONACCI NUMBERS
Fibonacci<-rep(0, 1000)
Fibonacci[0]<-1
Fibonacci[1]<-1
Product<-1

for (i in 2:1000)
{
    Fibonacci[i]<-(Fibonacci[i-1])+(Fibonacci[i-2])
    Product<-Fibonacci[i]*Product
}

Fibonacci[1000]
Product
```

This returns the following error:

```
Error in Fibonacci[i] <- (Fibonacci[X - 1]) + (Fibonacci[X - 2]) : 
  replacement has length zero
```

I am inclined to think I have misunderstood operating with different elements of an array (perhaps the i-2 in the vector description is not correct), but I haven't found anything over the past hour and a half which would have helped me correct it. 
So, any insights into the cause of the problem would be most appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A simple debugging technique is to insert `print(i)` at the beginning of the loop. That would have told you where the error occurred so you could figure out what the problem is.

Comment: I had a similar problem, took your advice, it doesn't work because we are getting the error, so no print() happens.

Answer (score 20):

Arrays in R are 1-based.

```
Fibonacci[1]<-1
Fibonacci[2]<-1
Product<-1
for (i in 3:1000)
{
```

(the remainder as in your question)

The problem is `Fibonacci[0]` which is a 0-length numeric.  When `i = 2`, this expression has a right hand side of `numeric(0)`:

```
Fibonacci[i]<-(Fibonacci[i-1])+(Fibonacci[i-2])
```

Comment: That was it; I began with 1 and everything worked perfectly. Thanks a lot! Although the 1000th Fibonacci number is 4.3*10^208, and the product of the first 1000 is displayed as "infinity". I guess there is not much to do about that, though...

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea! I was spinning a similar problem for 2 hours until I finally Googled it and found this. Huge help.