# R Error: replacement has length zero

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to identify the nearest position to indicate close position(cP).

Let's say I have the following:

```
indicator.Trade=c(1,1,0,0,-1,0,0,0,1,1,0,-1,-1)
cP=c(NA,NA,1,1,NA,-1,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,1,NA)

## If indicator.Trade[1] is 1, I want to obtain order.book[1,1]=1 and order.book[2,1]=3. 
## If indicator.Trade[2] is 1, I want to obtain order.book[1,2]=2 and order.book[2,2]=3.

order.book=matrix(0,nrow=2,ncol=(length(indicator.Trade)-1))
for(i in 1:(length(indicator.Trade)-1)){
   if( (indicator.Trade[i]==1) ){
       order.book[1,i]=i
       order.book[2,i]=head(which(cP[c((i):(length(indicator.Trade)-1))]==1),1)
   }    else if(indicator.Trade[i]==-1){
       order.book[1,i]=i
       order.book[2,i]=head(which(cP[c((i):(length(indicator.Trade)-1))]==-1),1)
   }    else {
       order.book[1,i]=i
       order.book[2,i]=0
   }
}
```

But running the code above I get the following error:

```
 in order.book[2, i] = head(which(cP[c((i):(length(indicator.Trade) -  : 
  replacement has length zero
```

I tried substituting manually:

```
i=1 and i=(length(indicator.Trade)-1)
```

As suggested in [Simple for loop in R producing "replacement has length zero" in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17665164/simple-for-loop-in-r-producing-replacement-has-length-zero-in-r) to check for numeric(0) but that doesn't seem to be the case. What am I missing here?

**Edit**

I've just realized that

```
head(which(cP[c(((length(indicator.Trade)-1)):(length(indicator.Trade)-1))]==1),1)
[1] 1
```

So, my code for finding the correct index position would be wrong. However, I'm still expecting it to run though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting that error, because you are trying to assign a value of length zero. Put this line of code `print(which(cP[c((i):(length(indicator.Trade)-1))]==-1))` inside `else if()` block and see the error comes from there. It is because `:` is used to get sequence between two numbers. Here you are trying to get the sequence with null value, which is invalid operation. It occurs for column 12 in the `else if` block. I added the print statement in the code below as well.

Try this small exercise to see what is happening

```
a1 <- NULL   # create a null variable
1:a1         # generate sequence using `:` 
# Error in 1:a1 : argument of length 0
```

This is why I used `seq_len` function in the for loop. Read `?seq_len` and `?seq_along` man pages.

Modified code

```
indicator.Trade=c(1,1,0,0,-1,0,0,0,1,1,0,-1,-1)
cP=c(NA,NA,1,1,NA,-1,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,1,NA)
len_ind_tr <- length(indicator.Trade)

order.book <- matrix(0,nrow=2,ncol=len_ind_tr-1)) 

for(i in seq_len(len_ind_tr-1)){
  if(indicator.Trade[i] == 1){
    order.book[1,i] <- i
    order.book[2,i] <- which(cP[i:(len_ind_tr-1)] == 1)[1]
  } else if(indicator.Trade[i] == -1){
    order.book[1,i] <- i
    order.book[2,i] <- which(cP[i:(len_ind_tr-1)] == -1)[1]
    print(which(cP[i:(len_ind_tr-1)] == -1))
  } else {
    order.book[1,i] <- i
    order.book[2,i] <- 0
  }
}

order.book
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
# [1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10    11    12
# [2,]    3    2    0    0    2    0    0    0    1     3     0    NA
```

Comment: Consider a case where I've bought shares at time: 1,3,4; which is indicator.Trade in this case.

Now, I want to sell my shares whenever a certain condition is met. So if the condition is met at time: 2,5... At time = 2, I want to sell shares from 1, and at time = 5, I want to sell shares from 3 and 4. That is the purpose of cP; to indicate when the condition is met. Hope that helps explaining what I'm doing. If possible, do you by any chance know how to obtain the correct index position?

Comment: I think when you say indexing, you are referring to subscripting and subsetting values from a data structure?

Comment: subscripting and subsetting can be done by `$`, `[ ]`, and `[[ ]]`. You choose one of them based the class of the variable

Comment: the function `which` gives you the index position. There are four types of subscript indices: 1. positive integers or numeric, 2. negative integers or numeric, 3. logical vectors and 4. character vectors. I used numeric value in the above code to get the first value. It is similar to using the function `head`.

Comment: I see. Thanks for pointing out my mistake and the explanation.